# Resolving promises on resolver using ui-router

Tags: javascript, angular.js, promise

We're rewriting some parts of our application. We're trying to avoid the promise anti-pattern and do things properly, but I'm not certain that we did so.

More precisely, we are rewriting the resolver of a state using ui-router.

```
.state( 'catalogue', {
  // skipped on purpose not relevant content
  resolve : 
    boxCreateData : function( $stateParams, $q, Basket, Customer ) {

      var defer = $q.defer(),
          basket = null,
          customer = null;

      Basket.fromApi( $stateParams.id )
        .then( function( basket ) {
          Customer.fromApi( basket.getCustomer() )
            .then( function( customer ) {
              defer.resolve( { basket : basket, customer : customer } );
            });
        });

      return defer.promise;

    }
});
```

`Basket.fromApi` and `Customer.fromApi` are static methods of their corresponding "class"es, `Basket` and `Customer`. Both implementations are like this (more or less; it's not the whole code, but it shows the concept. `Customer.fromApi` is the same):

```
Basket.fromApi = function( id ) {
  var defer = $q.defer();
  boxesResource.get( { id : id }, function( response ) {
    // various manipulation here with the response...
   defer.resolve( new Basket( ... ) );
  });
  return defer.promise;
};
```

Note we are using the `get` method of `$resource`.

The major issue here is that until we have the basket, we can't query the customer (because customer ID comes in the basket object).

We are querying first the basket with the basket ID. Once we have it, we can get the customer ID from the basket object and then, retrieve the customer object.

I just don't like the `then` pyramid. I'm not sure if we are missing something or in this case, there is no other way to do it.

Is there a cleaner way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: I can't quite tell from the question itself, so to clarify: This code _works_, but either looks ugly or doesn't work as well as you'd like it to.

Comment: I know this code works, its just Im not quite satisfied about having two nested promises. I think is something that it must be avoided. An anti-pattern. Or maybe its not. I just want to know if this is the proper way or not. Is there any way that allow me not to nest this promises ?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `$q.defer` unless you *have* to.

Here you can just return the promise:

```
Basket.fromApi = function (id) {
    return boxesResource.get({
        id: id
    }, function (response) {
        // various manipulation here with the response...
        return new Basket(...));
    });
};
```

You could really clean up the `resolve` by creating a new service:

**State**

```
.state('catalogue', {
    resolve: {
        boxCreateData: function($stateParams, boxCreateService) {
             return boxCreateService.getBoxCreateData($stateParams.id);
        }
    }
})
```

**Service**

```
app.service('boxCreateService', function(Basket, Customer) {
    this.getBoxCreateData = function(id) {
        return Basket.fromApi(id)
                .then(function (basket) {
                    return Customer.fromApi(basket.getCustomer())
                        .then(function (customer) {
                            return {
                                basket: basket,
                                customer: customer
                            };
                    });
                });
    };
});
```

There's not much you can do to avoid two nested promises here. You need the customer ID before you can get the customer.

[More on the deferred antipattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns).